# How to generate a reduced Excel when filtering by id in vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

In vb.net I have lists that contains variables of an Excel file.

Example:

Lists first Excel:

| ID | WEIGHT | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CAU65469 | 1234 | jkaufman |
| DEX74893 | 1234 | jdee |

Second one:

| ID | COLOR | VOLUME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CAU65469 | YELLOW | 900 |
| DEX743413 | BLUE | 1500 |

I want to generate a third file that looks like this:

| ID | WEIGHT | NAME | COLOR | VOLUME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CAU65469 | 1234 | jkaufman | YELLOW | 900 |

My solution is to shorten the second Excel by filtering by id
so it would only show me the data if the ID is found in both files and then comparing by coordinates.

On vb.net, how can I save the position of an Excel (index) by an ID in order to shorten the Excel?

My code in vb.net, I have the values in lists like this:

```
Public ID As New List(Of String)

Public ID2 As New List(Of String)

Public COLOR As New List(Of String)

Public NAME As New List(Of String)
Public  WEIGHT New List(Of String)
Public VOLUME As New List(Of String)
```

To just fill information in a new Excel I use this code.

I use a function like this to extract the information from the Excel files.

```
Function extraer_valores_planilla(ByRef ruta As String) As Boolean
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial
            Try
                Dim stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(ruta)
                Dim package = New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(stream)
                '//  Libro
                Dim Workbook = package.Workbook
                '//  Hojas
                Dim hojas = Workbook.Worksheets
    
                ' While (Workbook.Worksheets.Count >= aux)
                Dim hojaUsuarios = Workbook.Worksheets(Workbook.Worksheets.Item(0).ToString)
                Dim indice As Integer = 2
    
                While (indice < 5000)
                    
                    If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios.Cells("A" & indice).Value) = False) Then
                        ID.Add(hojaUsuarios.Cells("A" & indice).Value)
                    End If
                      indice += 1
            End While
            indice += 1
        Catch EX As Exception
            MsgBox(EX.ToString)
            Return False
        End Try
        Return True
```

and then I fill the third Excel like this:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial
        Dim path As String = seleccionardirectorio("Excel|.xlsx")
        If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path) = False) Then

            Dim excel = New ExcelPackage(New FileInfo(path))
            excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Hoja1")
            Dim aux As Integer = 1
            Dim Workbook = excel.Workbook
            Dim hojas = Workbook.Worksheets
            Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
            Dim hoja1 = Workbook.Worksheets("Hoja1")
            'DAMOS NOMBRE A LAS COLUMNAS 
            INICIALIZAR_PLANILLA(hoja1)
               While (aux <= ID.Count)

                hoja1.Cells("C" & aux + 1).Value = COLOR.Item(aux - 1)
                aux += 1

            End While
```

Comment: Need more info. Post some code showing how you have these objects arranged in your progam (post the classes that represent them, and the lists you have)

Comment: i put the code, now

Comment: The posted code does not show how ID2 Color, Volume, Weight, Name lists come to be populated with anything

Answer (score 0):

One of the things we (should) do when we write programs in an object oriented language, is try and move away from thinking like "I have to store 5 bits of info about an object - id, color, name, weight, volume. I'll make 5 arrays, one for each thing, and relate them all positionally so the "ID1 BLUE JOHN 50KG 200m3" data is at array index 9 in each of the five arrays"

Instead we should be thinking "I'll make a class with 5 properties, and I'll create instances of it and fill them" - this way the items of data don't remain related purely because they "just happen to all be at position 9 in some arrays" but instead are all together and representing an object. Nearly line of code you write in VB uses something that obeys this notion - you should too

```
Public Class Whatever

    Public Property ID As String
    Public Property Color As String
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Weight As String
    Public Property Volume As String
End Class
```

Next we use some collection that supports looking things up, like a Dictionary:

```
Function extraer_valores_planilla(ByRef ruta As String, isFirstExcel as Moolean) As Boolean

    ... 'put code that opens file here - i removed for clarity

    Dim das New Dictionary(Of String, Whatever)

    Dim indice As Integer = 2
    
    While (indice < 5000)
                    
        If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios.Cells("A" & indice).Value)) Then
            indice += 1
            Continue While
        End If

        Dim id = hojaUsuarios.Cells("A" & indice).Value

        If Not d.ContainsKey(id) Then d(id) = New Whatever

        d(id).ID = id

        If isFirstExcel Then
            d(id).Weight = hojaUsuarios.Cells("B" & indice).Value
            d(id).Name = hojaUsuarios.Cells("C" & indice).Value
        Else
            d(id).Color = hojaUsuarios.Cells("B" & indice).Value
            d(id).Volume = hojaUsuarios.Cells("C" & indice).Value

        indice += 1
    End While
```

**The posted code does not show how ID2 Color, Volume, Weight, Name lists come to be populated with anything**. I've assumed that WEIGHT/COLOR is in column B, and NAME/VOLUME is in column C

At the end of this operation you have a dictionary that has ID strings mapping to `Whatever` objects... And those objects Will have two or four properties filled in depending on if their ID was present in one file or the other